# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <scn == 3 ::scn == 4> in unknown function,

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I read alot  from other solution but i still confused what should i do with mine...

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    //create the cascade classifier object used for the face detection
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    //use the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml library
    face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    //setup video capture device and link it to the first capture device
    VideoCapture captureDevice;
    captureDevice.open(0);

    //setup image files used in the capture process
    Mat captureFrame;
    Mat grayscaleFrame;

    //create a window to present the results
    namedWindow("outputCapture", 1);

    //create a loop to capture and find faces
    while (true)
    {
        //capture a new image frame
        captureDevice >> captureFrame;

        //convert captured image to gray scale and equalize
        cvtColor(captureFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);

        //create a vector array to store the face found
        std::vector<Rect> faces;

        //find faces and store them in the vector array
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

        //draw a rectangle for all found faces in the vector array on the original image
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

            rectangle(captureFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        }

        //print the output
        imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);

        //pause for 33ms
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed  in unknown function

It seems the error happened after "captureDevice >> captureFrame;" Please guide me, this is taking image from camera.

Comment: You have forgotten to include `cv.h`.

Comment: I checked online about that, mostly if i wrote opencv2, they never call cv.h. i tried to put it but it didn't make any different.
btw, this is successfully built only problem during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `VideoCapture` can't grab frame from your camera. Add this code to check result of frame grabbing:

```
//create a loop to capture and find faces
while (true)
{
    //capture a new image frame
    captureDevice >> captureFrame;
    if (captureFrame.empty())
    {
        cout << "Failed to grab frame" << endl;
        break;
    }
    ...
```

If it is a problem of `VideoCapture` check that you installed drivers for your camera.

Comment: Yeah, it display "failed", is there any other way rather than install drivers? Last time i use code which using SDK things and it worked perfectly without problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using and which version of OpenCV? As I know 2.4.6 version had some issues with video on linux and the issue was fixed in 2.4.6.1.

Comment: windows 8, opencv 247

Comment: Probably you should ask another question or submit a bug and specify your camera model, driver version, OpenCV version (is it from installer or it was built by your own), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I know what happened. I tried running the program and it worked perfectly.

You have probably not linked the required DLL's.. Make sure (in case you are using Windows) your *opencv/bin* is included in your environment variables. This is my **CMakeLists.txt** file to make things easier for you,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(SO_example)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

SET (SOURCES
    #VTKtoPCL.h
    main.cpp
    )

add_executable(so_example ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(so_example ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: This is my first time using opencv, i follow online installation about shortcut in environment variables and creating OPENCV_DEBUG.pps. If what u mean with linked required dll things, everytime it asked, i copy to the folder "debug". If what you meant was not the one i talked about, please guide me step by step. I'm sorry i'm still learning.

Comment: You definitely don't need to do that. Follow the instructions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html). Once you have done everything there (including setting of the environment variables), then use the CMakeLists file I posted and your program should work fine.

Comment: Hi, i've been downloading it but it always fail in the middle. the worst part, i don't even know how to resume and restart again. it's wasting time. is there any other way rather than waiting that download. have been waiting whole day and keep failing

Comment: Try to download the source code and try using another compiler. I have tried to use VS 2013 before and it still has some compatibility issues with OpenCV.